# Javascript for while with mysql update when not having value

Tags: javascript, mysql

I will Update a Value in my Database when this is not setted.

I have this Code:

```
items.forEach(function(item,i,arr){
    mysqlConnection.query('UPDATE `SkinBank` SET `AssetID`=\'' + item.assetid + '\', `Status`=\'market\' WHERE `Status`=\'open\' AND `Tradeoffer` = \'' + offer.id + '\' AND `SkinName` = \'' + item.market_hash_name + '\'', function (err, row, fields) {});
});
```

When i put than 2 "Items" which has item.assetid (like: Item 1 has = 123123 and Items 2 has= 987987) than all two items who has nothing get the same Assetid value like 123123 or 987987.

How i can make, that he gives every item ONE AssetId.

Before this, the column "AssetID" has nothing in there

Comment: Look at your `item` array - the `assetid` must be the same for every item in that array. Likely the problem is upstream of this line.

Comment: @pherris in item array is 2 items with 2 different assetids. If i do "console.log(item.assetid)" i become 2 different ids back. But in database he set 1 assetid to 2 items...

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your `WHERE` clause is matching too many rows. It's not clear what library you are using, but if you are using `node-mysql` you can output the number of rows updated in the callback function:

```
connection.query('UPDATE `SkinBank` SET `AssetID`=\'' + item.assetid + '\', `Status`=\'market\' WHERE `Status`=\'open\' AND `Tradeoffer` = \'' + offer.id + '\' AND `SkinName` = \'' + item.market_hash_name + '\'', function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log('changed ' + result.changedRows + ' rows');
})
```

https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#getting-the-number-of-changed-rows

Comment: it says: "changed 2 rows, than
changed 0 rows". How can i make that he change 1, than 1?

Comment: That's the issue, you aren't matching the right rows to update in your `WHERE` clause. Probably you need to add the ID of the column to the update statement.

Comment: But how? I have Columns: ID, ItemName, Assetid - The ItemName can be the same, the Assetid must update for each Item. The AssetId is different and must be different. AssetID updated in this foreach. ID is 1 and counting up automaticly

Comment: Since you are doing an UPDATE you must be selecting the rows to change when you create the `items` array.  When creating your `items` array you need to include the `ID` column's value in the array, then in your `UPDATE` your where can become `WHERE ID=\'' item.id\''.

Comment: i have it! Thanks for this code. Thats helping me much! :) I add "ORDER BY AssetID DESC LIMIT 1". That works :)

Comment: This is a non-determanistic approach and I would not recommend it. Please consider the ID approach I suggested. If this answered your question, please be sure to click on the checkmark under the answer.